# How can I make this dropdown calculation work?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, time, dropdown, calculation

I'm fairly new to javascript, and I'm trying to calculate a value based on other dropdown values.

So there are three dropdowns, one for start time, one for end time and one for break time. There is a 4th input field for the total hours worked. Now, this is a manual field, but I intend to make this field automatically put in a value of the calculated time.

The page is build in wordpress with gravityforms.

Initially, I tried using jQuery hashes to retrieve the values, but that didn't work, so now I've used the Document.getElementById.

```
function CalcTime()
{
    var time1 = Document.getElementById('input_16_2').value();
    var time2 = Document.getElementById('input_16_3').value();
    var time3 = Document.getElementById('input_16_4').value();
    var time1 = time1.split(':');
    var time2 = time2.split(':');
    var time3 = time3.split(':');
    var hours1 = parseInt(time1[0], 10),
        hours2 = parseInt(time2[0], 10),
        hours3 = parseInt(time3[0], 10),
        mins1 = parseInt(time1[1], 10),
        mins2 = parseInt(time2[1], 10),
        mins3 = parseInt(time3[1], 10);
    var hours = hours2 - hours1 - hours3;
    var mins = 0;
    if(mins2 >= mins1) {
        mins = mins2 - mins1 - mins3;
    }
    else {
        mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
        hours--;
    }
    if(mins < 9)
    {
        mins = '0'+mins;
    }
    if(hours < 9)
    {
        hours = '0'+hours;
    }
    $("#time_duration").val(hours+':'+mins);
    Document.getElementById('input_16_5').value = $("#time_duration").val;
}

var showTime = Document.getElementById('input_16_5').value();

Document.getElementById('input_16_4').on("click", CalcTime)
{
    showTime.show();
}
```

When using the console it says I can't use `Document.getElementById` as a function, which I understand, however, I don't know what I can do to make it work.

Comment: JS is case sensitive, it's `document` that you're looking for not `Document`

Comment: `it says I can't use Document.getElementById as a function, which I understand,` This reads adorable. :D

Comment: oops, thanks! Though it still doesn't work and still gives the same error

Comment: can you make small https://jsfiddle.net/ link with all JS and HTML so I can take a closer look ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/10rsLz9g/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/3aud5xL4/

now it works (no errors). you're mixing jQuery and vanilla JS in same function, that's why it wasn't working

this is jQuery syntax

```
$("#time_duration").val(hours + ':' + mins);
```

this is vanilla JS version

```
document.getELementById('time_duration').value = hours + ':' + mins
```

try not to mix those 2 together, or you'll experience some odd results.
also convert this

```
document.getElementById('input_16_5').value = $("#time_duration").val;
```

into

```
document.getElementById('input_16_5').value = document.getElementById("time_duration").value;
```

and one more thing, you define same variables 2 times in your code. this is JS so it won't complain about it too much, but it's a bad practice. so this

```
var time1 = Document.getElementById('input_16_2').value();
...
var time1 = time1.split(':');
```

will become this

```
var time1 = Document.getElementById('input_16_2').value.split(':')
```

Comment: Thanks! this got me a whole lot further :)